# Fail to install facemorpher on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, linux, opencv, gcc, morphing

I have a **Ubuntu 18.04** and executed the packages from **requirements.txt** in the following Github repository https://github.com/alyssaq/face_morpher.

While installing facemorpher using the following command `pip3 install facemorpher` getting the errors given below. I don't find opencv2 folder

**Error Logs:**

```
In file included from src/py_wrapper.cpp:13:0:
src/stasm.h:33:10: fatal error: opencv2/opencv.hpp: No such file or directory
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;file='/tmp/pip-build-g5nna6ak/stasm/setup.py';f In file included from src/py_wrapper.cpp:13:0:
src/stasm.h:33:10: fatal error: opencv2/opencv.hpp: No such file or directory
#inc ----------------------------------------
lude "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;file='/tmp/pip-build-g5nna6ak/stasm/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(file);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, file, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-7nioxx18-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-g5nna6ak/stasm/
=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(file);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, file, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-7nioxx18-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-g5nna6ak/stasm/`
```